# spinner bar on specific div for a certain period of time

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on an angular project and I want to play spinner bar on a specific div .

I have a function in my Component file which calls an API and returns result.What I want is to do is when I call that function, I want spinner bar to display on the div and as soon as function returns all the results, I want spinner bar to hide.

I have tried something like this so far but it didn't work.

Initialized a Boolean variable in my component.ts file.

`let isLoopStarted : boolean = false;`

And in my HTML file,I have done something like this.

`<img src = "someGif.gif" [hidden] = "!isLoopStarted">`

When I call the function, I set the value of `isLoopStarted` to true.
Spinner bar starts displaying on the div. Now, when the function is about to terminate, I again set the value of `isLoopStarted` to false. Spinner bar should hide but it does not and keeps on displaying on the div forever until I refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that angular has detected changes in your component's scope. You can do this by using the @angular/http module for the AJAX call, or you can use the `changeDetectorRef`. See this example: https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#example

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like this:

```
<div *ngIf="isLoopStarted ; else dataReady">
    <img src = "someGif.gif">
</div>

<ng-template #dataReady>
    ...your rest of the component which you want to show/hide
</ng-template>
```

**Also,** make sure that `isLoopStarted` variable is changing.

Comment: Thanks. I have 2 queries.
1. My interpretation of *ngIf is that if *ngIf becomes false then It removes that div from DOM. Even though, later *ngIf becomes true, how can this div can be displayed since its already removed from DOM. Please correct me if I have wrong interpretation of *ngIf.

2. When function is called, My table on HTML file becomes filling with data.I want to display spinner bar while table is being filled with data. As soon as function is terminated and full data is being displayed on HTML table, I want my spinner bar to disappear. Will your code work in that condition?

Comment: Try it! It will work. And AFIK you got `*ngIf` right  :)

Comment: No, It didn't work. Probably you didn't really understand my scenario. I am already on a page. Initially, when I go to that page, the value of "isLoopStarted" is false. I click a button to call a function which returns some data. There is a for loop in my function. before I start for loop, I set the value of "isLoopStarted" to true. Now spinner bar should start showing. After the for loop ends, I again set the value of "isLoopStarted" to false. On setting the value of "isLoopStarted" to false, my spinner bar should disappear.